# Summing $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\frac{H_{2k} - 2H_{k}}{2n-2k-1} \binom{2k}{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

The sum in the question has a nice closed-form:
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\binom{2n - 2k}{n - k}
\frac{H_{2k} - 2H_{k}}{2n-2k-1}\binom{2k}{k} =
\frac{1}{n}\left[4^{n} - 3\binom{2n-1}{n}\right],$$
where $H_k$ is the harmonic number $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k.$

My proof is excruciating:

- It involved the specialization of a two-variable generating function ( $x$ and $y$ take different functions of $t$ ) so that I could use an identity that seems to have no mere
  mortal-constructed proof ( a variant of the WZ method was used, I believe ).
- In the process of the proof, I noticed that the expression in big parentheses on the RHS is a sequence of integers, and I searched the OEIS to find $A213119$.
- As logarithms are involved, it was a matter of talking the arguments into the logarithm to find that my generating function was indeed equal to implied by the right hand side of the equation.

I seek a simpler, more direct proof.

A contributor wanted to know where the identity originated.  It originated as an attempt to prove the very pretty

$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^{2}H_{k} =
\binom{2n}{n}\left(\,{2H_{n} - H_{2n}}\,\right)
$$

It may be impossible not to use this in any attempted proof, but hopefully, the specialization of a two-variable generating function can be avoided.

Comment: Where did this sum come from?

Comment: @IgorRivin I added some information to answer your question in the problem statement.

Comment: I have a vague recollection that the last identity might have a combinatorial proof.

Comment: The added identity at the end of the question is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798754/prove-that-sum-j-0nh-jn-choose-j2-2n-choose-n-left2h-n-h-2n-right?noredirect=1) and [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h352146p1900404).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for the reference to a proof I can work through myself.

Comment: @skbmoore: My pleasure!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the following I  present a proof to show that it  can be done and
perhaps  inspire  additional  efforts  at  further  simplification.  A
combinatorial proof would be quite nice.

We seek to verify the identity

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {2n-2k\choose n-k} 
\frac{H_{2k} - 2H_k}{2n-2k-1} {2k\choose k}
= \frac{1}{n} \left[4^n - 3 {2n-1\choose n}\right].$$

**Preliminary.** We get for the first piece in $H_{2k}$ call it $A$
that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {2n-2k\choose n-k} 
\frac{1}{2n-2k-1} {2k\choose k}
[z^{2k}] \frac{1}{1-z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {2k\choose k} 
\frac{1}{2k-1} {2n-2k\choose n-k}
[z^{2n-2k}] \frac{1}{1-z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}$$

We may raise $k$ to $n$ because the function in $z$ has no constant
term:

$$[z^{2n}] \frac{1}{1-z} \log\frac{1}{1-z} 
\sum_{k=0}^{n} {2k\choose k} 
\frac{1}{2k-1} {2n-2k\choose n-k} z^{2k}$$

Now the coefficient extractor enforces the  upper limit of the sum and
we get  (in fact  expansions start at  $z^{2k+1}$ which  cancels $k=n$
already)

$$[z^{2n}] \frac{1}{1-z} \log\frac{1}{1-z} 
\sum_{k\ge 0} {2k\choose k} 
\frac{1}{2k-1} {2n-2k\choose n-k} z^{2k}
\\ = - [z^{2n}] \frac{1}{1-z} \log\frac{1}{1-z} 
[w^n] \sqrt{1-4wz^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4w}}.$$

The same method yields for the second piece in $H_k$ call it $B$

$$- [z^{n}] \frac{1}{1-z} \log\frac{1}{1-z} 
[w^n] \sqrt{1-4wz} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4w}}.$$

**First part.** Continuing with piece $B$

$$[w^n] \sqrt{1+\frac{4w(1-z)}{1-4w}}
= - [w^n] \sum_{k\ge 0} {2k\choose k} \frac{1}{2k-1}
(-1)^k \frac{w^k (1-z)^k}{(1-4w)^k}
\\ = - \sum_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k} \frac{1}{2k-1}
(-1)^k [w^{n-k}] \frac{(1-z)^k}{(1-4w)^k}
\\ = - 4^n \sum_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k} \frac{1}{2k-1}
(-1)^k (1-z)^k 4^{-k} {n-1\choose k-1}$$

and extracting the coefficient in $[z^n]$

$$4^n \sum_{k=1}^n {2k\choose k} \frac{1}{2k-1}
(-1)^k 4^{-k} {n-1\choose k-1}
[z^n] (1-z)^{k-1} \log\frac{1}{1-z}
\\ = 4^n \sum_{k=1}^n {2k\choose k} \frac{1}{2k-1}
(-1)^k 4^{-k} {n-1\choose k-1}
\sum_{q=0}^{k-1} (-1)^q {k-1\choose q} \frac{1}{n-q}.$$

Now

$${n-1\choose k-1} {k-1\choose q}
= \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!\times q! \times (k-1-q)!}
= {n-1\choose q} {n-1-q\choose k-1-q}$$

Switching the order of the summation,

$$4^n \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q}
\frac{(-1)^q}{n-q} \sum_{k=q+1}^n
{n-1-q\choose k-1-q} {2k\choose k}
\frac{1}{2k-1} (-1)^k 4^{-k}
\\ = \frac{4^n}{n} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n\choose q}
(-1)^q \sum_{k=q+1}^n
{n-1-q\choose k-1-q} {2k\choose k}
\frac{1}{2k-1} (-1)^k 4^{-k}
\\ = - \frac{4^n}{n} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n\choose q}
(-1)^q \sum_{k=q+1}^n
{n-1-q\choose k-1-q} [z^k] \sqrt{1+z}.$$

The inner sum is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1-q}
{n-1-q\choose k} [z^{k+q+1}] \sqrt{1+z}
= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1-q}
{n-1-q\choose k} [z^{n-k}] \sqrt{1+z}
\\ = [z^n] \sqrt{1+z} 
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1-q} {n-1-q\choose k} z^k
= [z^n] \sqrt{1+z} (1+z)^{n-1-q}.$$

Substitute into the outer sum to get

$$- \frac{4^n}{n} [z^n] \sqrt{1+z}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n\choose q} (-1)^q (1+z)^{n-1-q}
= - \frac{4^n}{n} [z^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z}} 
(- (-1)^n + z^n)
\\ = - \frac{4^n}{n} 
\left(- 4^{-n} {2n\choose n} + 1\right)
= - \frac{4^n}{n} + {2n\choose n} \frac{1}{n}.$$

**Second part.** Here we may recycle the first segment
from the easy piece $B$ and obtain for piece $A$

$$4^n \sum_{k=1}^n {2k\choose k} \frac{1}{2k-1}
(-1)^k 4^{-k} {n-1\choose k-1}
[z^{2n}] (1-z^2)^{k-1} (1+z) \log\frac{1}{1-z}.$$

The coefficient extractor in $z$ has two parts, the first of which is

$$\sum_{q=0}^{k-1} (-1)^q {k-1\choose q} \frac{1}{2n-2q}$$

which contributes half the value of the piece $B.$
The second is

$$\sum_{q=0}^{k-1} (-1)^q {k-1\choose q} \frac{1}{2n-1-2q}.$$

This yields

$$-4^n [z^n] \sqrt{1+z} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q}
\frac{(-1)^q}{2n-1-2q} (1+z)^{n-1-q}
\\ = -4^n [z^n] \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q}
\frac{(-1)^q}{2n-1-2q} (1+z)^{n-1/2-q}
\\ = -4^n  \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q}
\frac{(-1)^q}{2n-1-2q} (n-1/2-q)^{\underline{n}}/n!.$$

We have for the falling factorial

$$  \prod_{p=0}^{n-1} (n-1/2-q-p)
= \frac{1}{2^n}  
\prod_{p=0}^{n-1} (2n-1-2q-2p)
\\ = \frac{1}{2^n}  
\prod_{p=-(n-1)}^0 (1-2q-2p)
= \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}  
\prod_{p=q-(n-1)}^{q} (2p-1)
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2^n}  
\frac{(2q-1)!}{2^{q-1} (q-1)!}
\prod_{p=q-(n-1)}^{-1} (2p-1).$$

With $2q-2(n-1)-1 = 2q-2n+1$ this finally becomes

$$\frac{(-1)^{q}}{2^n}  
\frac{(2q-1)!}{2^{q-1} (q-1)!}
\frac{(2n-1-2q)!}{2^{n-1-q} (n-1-q)!}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{q}}{2^{2n-1}}  
\frac{(2q)!}{q!}
\frac{(2n-1-2q)!}{(n-1-q)!}.$$

This was for $1\le q\le n-1.$ We get for $q=0$

$$\frac{1}{2^n} \prod_{p=-(n-1)}^0 (1-2p)
= \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{(2n-1)!}{2^{n-1} (n-1)!}$$

and we  see that the generic  term in four factorials  represents this
case correctly as well.

Returning to the sum we obtain

$$-\frac{2}{n}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2q\choose q}
{2n-2-2q\choose n-1-q}
\\ = -\frac{2}{n} [z^{n-1}] 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}
= -\frac{2}{n} [z^{n-1}] \frac{1}{1-4z} 
= -\frac{2}{n} 4^{n-1} = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{4^n}{n}.$$

**Conclusion.** We now collect the three pieces
with $A$ first then $B:$

$$-\frac{1}{2} \frac{4^n}{n} 
- \frac{1}{2} \frac{4^n}{n} 
+ \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{n} {2n\choose n}
\\ + 2 \frac{4^n}{n} - 2 \frac{1}{n} {2n\choose n}
= \frac{4^n}{n} - \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{n} {2n\choose n}
= \frac{4^n}{n} - 3 \frac{1}{n} {2n-1\choose n-1}.$$

This is indeed

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{n}
\left[4^n - 3 {2n-1\choose n}\right].}$$

Comment: $+1$.   Great Marko.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Impressive derivation! (+1)

Comment: @Marko Riedel I'm working through the details of the proof, but I've got the gist of it.  I'll leave the problem open for a few more days.  Yours, and the solution below it, both achieve the desired result -- avoid a specialization of a 2-variable generating function -- but I'd hardly call it easy!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variation.

> We observe the left-hand side of OPs identity is the coefficient of a Cauchy-product of series and we start with separating the factors. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}&\color{blue}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\frac{H_{2k}-H_k}{2n-2k-1}\binom{2k}{k}\right)z^n}\\
> &=\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\binom{2m}{m}\left(H_{2m}-2H_m\right)z^m\right)
> \left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{2l}{l}\frac{1}{2l-1}z^l\right)\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

We will make use from the generating functions of the *[central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)* and of the closely related *[Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof)*.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}z^n&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\\
C(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{n+1}z^n&=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We start with the easy part of (1) and consider the right-hand series. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{l=0}^\infty}\color{blue}{\binom{2l}{l}\frac{1}{2l-1}z^{l}}
> &=-1+2z\sum_{l=1}^\infty\binom{2l-1}{l-1}\frac{1}{2l-1}z^{l-1}\tag{3}\\
> &=-1+2z\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{2l}{l}\frac{1}{l+1}z^l\tag{4}\\
> &=-1+2z\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\right)\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=-\sqrt{1-4z}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
> and observe we have in (5) the generating function $C(z)$ of the Catalan numbers in disguise.

*Comment:*

- In (3) we separate the first term and use $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.
- In (4) we use $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$ and shift the index to start with $l=0$.
- In (5) we use $C(z)$ and simplify afterwards.

This was the warm-up section. Now we consider the left-hand series of (1). But prior to this we recall a nice polynomial identity in the following intermezzo.

**Intermezzo:** We introduce *generalised harmonic numbers* $H_n(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j+x}$ and consider the following polynomial in $x$ and $n,k$ non-negative integers:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\binom{n+x}{k}&=\frac{1}{k!}\frac{d}{dx}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n+x-j)\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}\prod_{{j=0}\atop{j\ne l}}^{k-1}(n+x-j)\\
&=\binom{n+x}{k}\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{n+x-l}\\
&=\binom{n+x}{k}\left(H_n(x)-H_{n-k}(x)\right)\tag{7}\\
\end{align*}
Evaluating the identity (7) at $x=0$ results in
\begin{align*}
\left.\left(\frac{d}{dx}\binom{n+x}{k}\right)\right|_{x=0}=\binom{n}{k}\left(H_n-H_{n-k}\right)\tag{8}
\end{align*}

> Now we are ready to tackle the left-hand series of (1). We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{m=1}^\infty}&\color{blue}{\binom{2m}{m}\left(H_{2m}-2H_m\right)z^m}\\
> &=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\binom{2m}{m}\left(H_{2m}-H_m\right)z^m-\sum_{m=1}^\infty\binom{2m}{m}H_mz^m\\
> &=\left.\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\binom{2m+x}{m}z^m\right)\right)\right|_{x=0}
> -\sum_{m=1}^\infty\binom{2m}{m}H_mz^n\tag{9}\\
> &=\left.\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\right)^x\right)\right)\right|_{x=0}
> -\sum_{m=1}^\infty\binom{2m}{m}H_mz^n\tag{10}\\
> &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\left.\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(C(z)\right)^x\right)\right|_{x=0}
> -\sum_{m=1}^\infty\binom{2m}{m}H_mz^n\\
> &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\left.\left(\left(C(z)\right)^x\ln C(z)\right)\right|_{x=0}
> -\sum_{m=1}^\infty\binom{2m}{m}H_mz^n\tag{11}\\
> &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\ln C(z)-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}{2\sqrt{1-4z}}\right)\tag{12}\\
> &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\ln C(z)+\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\ln\left(C(z)\sqrt{1-4z}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\left(3\ln C(z)+2\ln\sqrt{1-4z}\right)}\tag{13}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (9) we apply the identity (8) from the intermezzo.
- In (10) we use a generalised generating function of the central binomial coefficients. A derivation of it can be found for instance at *[this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4025969/binomial-identity-arising-from-catalan-recurrence/4029787#4029787)*.
- In (11) we make the derivation.
- In (12) we use the identity (9) stated in *[this paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL19/Chen/chen21.pdf)* by H. Chen, which is certainly a formidable source to derive many different variations of proofs of the current problem. We do some simplifications in the following lines.

> Putting (13) and (6) in (1) we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}&\color{blue}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\frac{H_{2k}-H_k}{2n-2k-1}\binom{2k}{k}\right)z^n}\\
> &=\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\binom{2m}{m}\left(H_{2m}-2H_m\right)z^m\right)
> \left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{2l}{l}\frac{1}{2l-1}z^l\right)\\
> &=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\left(3\ln C(z)+2\ln\sqrt{1-4z}\right)\right)\left(-\sqrt{1-4z}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\ln\frac{1}{1-4z}-3\ln C(z)}\tag{14}
> \end{align*}

Finally we calculate the generating functions from the right hand side of OP's identity.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}&\color{blue}{\frac{1}{n}\left(4^n-3\binom{2n-1}{n}\right)z^n}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\left(4z\right)^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\frac{1}{n}z^n\\
> &=\ln\frac{1}{1-4z}-\frac{3}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{n}z^n\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\ln\frac{1}{1-4z}-3\ln C(z)}\tag{15}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with (14) and the claim follows.

The term $\ln C(z)$ in (15) follows from (2) by division by $z$ and integrating both sides of the generating function of the central binomial coefficients. Note, this is also stated in Chen's paper shortly after corollary 4.

Comment: Good work! Will study in detail. (+1). Note that there is a proof of the identity from Chen's paper at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4025969/).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks for the credit and also for the hint, Marko. I've replaced the reference with the ref to the MSE link, which is much more convenient. :-)